# FIle won't compile

Tags: java, cmd

Yo, I'm trying to compile a file, it won't compile.

I've tried changing the path, but my path seems to be right. javac works fine.

```
public class BeerSong{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int beerNum = 99;
    String word = "bottles";

    while (beerNum >0){
        if(beerNum == 1){
            word = "bottle";
        }

            System.out.println(beerNum+" "+word+" of beer on the wall!");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " of beer.");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum-1;

            if(beerNum>0){
                System.out.println(beerNum+" "+word+" of beer on the wall!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("No more bottels of beer on the wall.");
            }
    }
}
```

}

The file is saved as BeerSong.java
After I go to the right directory in command prompt and type "javac BeerSong.java" I get this **error**:

```
BeerSong.java:1: error: error while writing BeerSong: BeerSong.class
(The system cannot find the file specified) public class BeerSong{
    ^ 1 error
```

Comment: Did you check that the directory is writable as your current user?

Comment: Why did you tag the question `runtime-error` if the file won't *compile*? Compilation errors and runtime errors are not the same thing.

Comment: Yea, I'm running command prompt in admin mode. 
I untagged runtime-error, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running `javac Beersong.java` which is not the same as 
 `javac BeerSong.java` (observe uppercase `S`).

Reason is the file system you are running is case sensitive

Comment: I’ll correct my answer. Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I am running "javac BeerSong.java" Type on the question mb xD

my PATH is> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin

Comment: Where are you running the command from. Is the file in the same directory as you are typing the command?

Comment: I'm running it from within a file on the desktop, I change the directory to the file everytime I run it.

Comment: @Newguy, I think something is wrong with your path. If you try `java -version` in that directory what is the output? I mean, the java class itself is fine, I've tested it locally and it compiled successfully

Comment: @Newguy maybe something related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058680/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-java-error-while-writing-test

Comment: C:\ stuff\ java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: exactly the same error yes

Comment: It works on everything except the desktop, I believe its a windows user error